# C# Code to change the fonts for all numbers

Tags: c#, fonts

I'm creating a clock program and I am implementing an option within the program that allow users to change the fonts of all the clock numbers

Problem is, I have a chunk of code that has all the numbers of the clock, and all of them are written individually; including the fonts. (see below)

```
    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create graphics
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        //get time
        int ss = DateTime.Now.Second;
        int mm = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;


        int[] handCoord = new int[2];

        //clear
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        //draw circle
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black, 1f), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //draw figure
        g.DrawString("1", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(210, 20));
        g.DrawString("2", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(259, 72));
        g.DrawString("3", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(280, 140));
        g.DrawString("4", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("5", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("6", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(142, 282));
        g.DrawString("7", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("8", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("9", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 140));
        g.DrawString("10", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("11", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(286, 140));
        g.DrawString("12", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(140, 2));

        //second hand
        handCoord = msCoord(ss, secHAND);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 1f), new Point(cx, cy), new Point(handCoord[0], handCoord[1]));

        //minute hand
        handCoord = msCoord(mm, minHAND);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2f), new Point(cx, cy), new Point(handCoord[0], handCoord[1]));

        //hour hand
        handCoord = hrCoord(hh % 12, mm, hrHAND);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray, 3f), new Point(cx, cy), new Point(handCoord[0], handCoord[1]));

        //load bmp in picturebox1
        clockpic.Image = bmp;

        //disp time
        this.Text = "Clock -  " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;

        //dispose
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out a better way to write a code, maybe one line of code that will allow me to change the fonts of all the numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Have you learned how to assign text to string variables, like for example `font_name = "Times New Roman"` ? Have you learned how to define a function, like for example `DrawOneClockNumber(  digit, font_name, ... )` ? There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Is your clock program a GUI or a console? If it's a GUI, then I can help you. 
Copy and paste this whole block of code to your program. This is your font dialog. (don't forget to set it manually from your toolbox before using this code)

```
    private void FontsMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the dialog.
        DialogResult result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // See if OK was pressed.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Get Font.
            Font = fontDialog1.Font;
        }
    }
```

Then change this line from your code...

```
g.DrawString("1", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(210, 20));
```

to this line...

```
g.DrawString("1", Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(210, 20));
```

Repeat it for all your number (1-to-12)